# How to make a constant loop that fires every second (without sleep or threading)?

Tags: python, backend, pythonanywhere

I am creating a new website (online web game) which requires a constant loop on the backend which fires every second. When I was hosting on my computer I had done it using `Threading.Timer(1, countTimer).start()`, but when I've done my research now it seems like pythonanywhere doesn't support Threading.

I can't use `Time.sleep` since that freezes the entire program and other stuff needs to run in the same file.

The file where the loop is would obviously be a always on task on pythonanywhere.

So basically, how should I go about making a function trigger every second on my python backend, without also freezing the entire thing, and not using any threading? Thank you!

Comment: Try checking out [what PythonAnywhere says about "Async Work"](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AsyncInWebApps/) - [here](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/172/) is a link on "always-on tasks"

Comment: PythonAnywhere doesn't support threading in web apps. You can use AlwaysOn task in the while True loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [Scheduled tasks](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ScheduledTasks/).

Follow the instructions at the link and schedule your script (containing a loop in your case) to run any time you want.

Comment: I know of the scheduled tasks but I am looking for something that is running all the time, the scheduled tasks only allow me to make something run every hour at most. I want a function triggered exactly every second.